# How exactly does the InnoDB engine in MySQL update its main data storage files?

Tags: mysql, innodb

It's come to my attention in the course of testing Linux's Back In Time backup utility that I can't understand how MariaDB actually saves data.

After adding a bogus record to a table and leaving it until the next snapshot happened I was surprised to find that restoring the older snapshot (taken before the bogus record added) did not result in the bogus record being removed.

I tried this two more times: bogus new record added, snapshot occurs (automatically, because that's what I've told Back In Time to do) ... and restore does not do what I'd expected.

Looking at the actual “Modified by” files, in the main directory (where all the databases are subdirectories) I find that only two files appear to have changed: `ib_logfile0` and `ib_logfile1`.  When configuring my Back In Time job I deliberately missed these out of the configuration because I assumed they were "just logs". Clearly NOT.

To solve my immediate problem it appears that all I have to do is include these two files in my snapshots. But how or by what process does `ibdata1` get updated with the new information? Is it perhaps when the MySQL service is shut down? Or started up?

What's odd is that I don't seem to find much information out there about this.

Comment: Thanks... that's a helpful clue.  InnoDB-specific, OK.  Shutdown and delete, OK. But for a continuous process of snapshotting whilst working on a database one obviously has to keep snapshots of the differing versions `ib_logfile0/1` ... You seem to imply that MySQL does indeed update `ibdata1` when it shuts down... but what happens in the event of a brutal poweroff of a machine?  Obviously I can do experiments myself to try to find answers...

Comment: Mike - I will tell you what configuration I prefer with MySQL InnoDB Engine is the [File-Per-Table Tablespaces](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-file-per-table-intro.html).... Much more flexibility once you start using this. This is literally a file per table configuration.... Crazy!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use a generic backup utility like Back in Time to backup databases.

As you've discovered you need a consistent snapshot of database files to have a workable backup. Without it you'll end up with something that isn't correct or just fails to start. The problem is that `ib_logfile*` are temporarily stores than then gets migrated to the tablespaces. You can only delete these if you cleanly shutdown (which is more that a systemctl stop mysqld)  which obviously didn't happen when you did the backup.

So in short for MySQL, use a backup program that is aware of MySQL (mysqldump, mydumper, xtrabackup), or a consistent snapshot tool (llvm snapshots or a filesystem based consistent snapshot functionality) or a replication slave an one of the previous methods.

Messing with MySQL data files from outside MySQL will only result in dataloss. Don't do it.

Comment: Thanks... as I am beginning to understand: a whole can of worms.  What happens when a machine with MySQL dbases gets a brutal power-off, for example, e.g. nothing to do with willed user action? I'm sure there are answers out there and I must try searching (again).  I'll certainly try searching on these "consistent snapshot tools" You don't have any useful links I suppose? Or hints about the sort of protocols you personally use?

Comment: MySQL, like other databases takes on ACID principles, the most being durability. brutal power is a form of point in time snapshot. Enough state has been taken so every transaction that returned to the user as successful will exist in the innodb log files to be replayed/applied when the service restarts. The undo log of transactions in process gets rolled back. lvm snapshot could be used (not llvm as I typoed), mysqldump has a --single-transaction, database size, io bandwidth, acceptable recovery time all play a part in which mechanism(s) are used. I suggest a new question :-)